# xslt - multiple sets of page numbers in the same document, extra page being generated

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

So, I am new to xml and xslt. I am in the process of building out an xml file with an accompanying stylesheet. Most of the data is currently hard-coded into the xml. This is a snippet of my xsl (apologies: I'm having some issues getting the whole file to meet Stack's formatting standards):

```
<xsl:template match="/packingList" priority="1">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="basicSPM"
                page-width="8.5in" page-height="11.0in"
                margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.5in" margin-left="1.0in" margin-right="1.0in" >
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="0.4in" />
                <fo:region-before />
                <fo:region-after />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="basicSPM" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="no-force">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block />
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="font-footer">
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="50%" />
                        <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="50%" />
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell column-number="1" text-align="left">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Print date :
                                        <xsl:value-of select="//currentDateTime" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell column-number="2" text-align="right">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Page
                                        <fo:page-number />
                                        of
                                        <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="sectionPageNumberTotal" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="documentType" />
                <fo:block id="sectionPageNumberTotal" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

There are two things that I would like to do that am not currently able to:

1. Remove the extra page (with a footer) generated when the pdf is generated. I've found that if I comment out this line -

   `<fo:block id="sectionPageNumberTotal" />`

   -the extra page goes away, but so, too, does part of my page numbering.  What is happening with that fo:block that is causing it the document to extend to another page?  I've tried a variety of force-page-count values, but I'm not sure they're relevant in this case.
2. Also, I want to restart the numbering of the PDF's pages to correspond with each documentType, so if there are 3 pages of Non-emergency documents, those pages would be numbered 1 of 3, 2 of 3, and 3 of 3, then the numbering would restart for emergency documents 1 of N, 2 of N, etc, and the same for the other document types.  I've tried a variety of solutions I've found on stack overflow, but I haven't had any luck, making me wonder if there is something that is fundamentally off about how I put this sheet together.  If not, I may end up rendering the different document types separately and then appending them together to achieve the desired numbering effect.
   Thanks in advance!

   ```
   <packingList>
   <dateRange th:text="${startDate} + ' to ' + ${endDate}"></dateRange>
   <currentDateTime th:text="${currentDateTime}"></currentDateTime>
   <documentType>
       <name>Non-Emergency</name>
       <packageActions>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>100000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>3701_75_04_PH_FF_A_RU_20160201_0539.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3701_75_04_PH_FF_A_RS_20160201_0539.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3701_99_04_PH_FF_A_RU_20160201_0539.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>200000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>5101$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_R_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>5101$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_N_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
       </packageActions>
   </documentType>
   <documentType>
       <name>Emergency</name>
       <packageActions>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>300000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>4707$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_R_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>4707$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_N_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>400000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>3309-1-12_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
       </packageActions>
   </documentType>
   <documentType>
       <name>Public Hearing Notice</name>
       <packageActions>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>500000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>145$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_R_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>145$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_N_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>600000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>2222-1-12_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>2222-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>2222-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>2222-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
       </packageActions>
   </documentType>
   <documentType>
       <name>Correction Letters</name>
       <packageActions>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>700000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>4444$2-47-23$1_PH_FF_R_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>4444$3-47-23$1_PH_FF_N_RU_20160201_0932.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
           <packageAction>
               <packageActionId>800000</packageActionId>
               <fileNames>
                   <fileName>8505-1-12_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-12_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-12_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-12_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>8505-1-44_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-56_FYR_C_RS_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
                   <fileName>3309-1-58_FYR_C_RU_20160201_1007.pdf</fileName>
               </fileNames>
           </packageAction>
       </packageActions>
   </documentType>
   <documentType>
       <name>Guides</name>
       <guideDocs>
           <guideDoc>
               <fileName>RMG_109_20160818.pdf</fileName>
               <agency>Environmental Protection Agency</agency>
               <dateReceived>7/7/17</dateReceived>
           </guideDoc>
           <guideDoc>
               <fileName>guides.pdf</fileName>
               <agency>California Legislative Services</agency>
               <dateReceived>8/8/17</dateReceived>
           </guideDoc>
       </guideDocs>
   </documentType>
   ```